# Catch Error Unhandled promise rejection warning

Tags: javascript, promise

I did the same catch error on another file and it works but failed on this one. The only different I made is added two parameters, any idea?

```
app.get('/getearth', (req, res) => {
  const lat = req.query.lat;
  const lon = req.query.lon;
  const date = req.query.date;
  const querystr = `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/earth/imagery?lon=${lon}&lat=${lat}&date=${date}&cloud_score=True&api_key=${apikey}`;

  axios
    .get(querystr)
    .then(response => {
      const earth = new Earth({
        cloud_score: response.data.cloud_score,
        date: response.data.date,
        url: response.data.url
      });
      if (!earth.date || !earth.lon || !earth.lat) {
        res.status(200).json('Not found');
        return;
      }
      earth
        .save()
        .then(response => {
          res.status(200).json(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          res.status(400).json(error);
        });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      res.status(400).json(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you need to have `return earth`.

Comment: btw, you can `throw` the `error` object from the inner `catch` statement, when attempting to save earth. The outer catch will pick it up. This will help prevent weird cases, where you are trying to respond to a client 2 times.

Comment: @ischenkodv added, doesn't work :(

Comment: @EvanBechtol I don't understand, can you show me?

Comment: @Alois Sure, check out [this example](https://codepen.io/evanbechtol/pen/dQqVrv). Also, you typically don't want to nest promises. If possible you want to chain them! [Here is an example of chaining with your code](https://codepen.io/evanbechtol/pen/oQPoNW?)

Comment: @EvanBechtol Thanks a lot! But still get the same error

Comment: @Alois did you also try the advice of ischenkodv?

Comment: What is the error that your promise is getting rejected with? Which of the promises is it?

Comment: @Bergi I have 3 errors, the first one is: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON; And the last two is: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection.

Comment: @EvanBechtol yes I did, it doesn't work as well :(

Comment: Then probably `res.status(400).json(error);` is throwing that error (`error` is circular), and of couse if it throws in the `catch` clause that isn't handled anywhere. Try a) appending another `.catch(console.error)` to suppress the unhandled rejection and log the error b) `.json(error.message)` to fix the mistake

Comment: @Alois The `catch` block catches exception but then throws another one when trying to stringify circular JSON. Do you really need to return that JSON? If not, just return error message `res.status(400).json({error: 'Error fetching data'});`.